# Change Servlet publish location?

Tags: java, html, servlets, jsoup, web.xml

So I have this problem where I have my html files in a certain structure, example:

- WebContent

  - Admin

    - Page1.html
    - Page2.html
  - Extras

    - Page3.html
  - WEB-INF
  - META-INF

I´m using a form tag which redirects the request to the appropriate servlet file, in the servlet file (java) I use JSOUP to load the content, modify it and send it back as a new webpage. My problem is resource are not getting loaded (such as images, js and css) since servlet publish the file in the root folder. Is their any way to change the default publish site for that specific html?

So for example If I load Page3.html I want it to be able to posted it under the Extras folder not the WebContent folder.

Thanks

Comment: This setup of yours seems highly unusual to mee (or I did not get it at all). Can you please describe in more detail why you use JSoup in such a context. Do you not create the HTML page with some sort of template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is resource are not getting loaded (such as images, js and css)

#### TL;DR

Either:

- Edit HTML files to make the resources urls relative to WebContent folder
- Ask Jsoup to change resources urls into absolute ones.

---

Let's dive into the second option.

During the modifications, the code need to set the resources urls properly. Jsoup can help you here. To do so, there is a two steps process:

1. Set the document `baseuri`
2. Ask Jsoup to turn any url into an absolute one

### 1) Set the document `baseuri`

The way you set the `baseuri` will depend on how you load the content with Jsoup.

#### Jsoup.connect

This is the easiest way to do it. Jsoup will set the baseuri for you.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); // Document is parsed with baseuri set.
```

- If url host is the server hosting your servlets there may be a code smell here.
- If the url is another server, you'll need to parse the document like below:

```
Jsoup.parse( //
  Jsoup.connect(otherServerUrl).response().body(), //
  "http://resources-site.com/" //
);
```

#### Jsoup.parse

Choose the most appropriate signature for your case in the signatures below and set the baseUri:

```
Jsoup.parse(html, baseUri);
Jsoup.parse(in, charsetName, baseUri);   
Jsoup.parse(html, baseUri, parser);
Jsoup.parse(in, charsetName, baseUri, parser);    
Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(bodyHtml, baseUri);
```

You may check also the sister method `Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(bodyHtml, baseUri)`.

#### 2) Ask Jsoup to turn any url into an absolute one

Once the baseuri is set, it's time to make urls absolute. See the following Java 8 code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
Map<String, String> attributesNames = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("a", "href");
        put("img", "src");
    }
};

for (Element elt : doc.select(String.join(",", attributesNames.keySet())) {
    String elementTagName = elt.tagName();
    String attributeName = attributesNames.get(elementTagName);

    if (attributeName == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected element: " + elementTagName);
    }

    elt.attr(attributeName, elt.absUrl(attributeName));
}
```

Comment: I didn´t knew you could that, what I ended up doing was turn my html to JSP and use the getAbsolutePath method to retrieve the entire location of the servlet then I just completed it using the destination folder. But I just tried it, it also works